# Workflow persistence - WebServiceInputActivity

Tags: persistence, workflow-foundation

[alt text http://home.elka.pw.edu.pl/~pkolodzi/Capture.PNG](http://home.elka.pw.edu.pl/~pkolodzi/Capture.PNG)

I have created the **IAdder** interface with two methods: **PassA** and **PassB**. My workflow starts with **webServiceInputActivity1** which is activated by **PassA** remote call. Another element in my workflow is another **webServiceInputActivity2** element. This time the "IsActivating" property is set to false. I expect my workflow to be persisted after first activity finishes (which does return void). The workflow should be reactivated by calling PassB web method.

After publishing workflow as web service and invoking PassA here is what I get:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: Workflow with id &quot;b0c5f9dd-57f3-427f-b172-17d4663f7eaf&quot; not found in state persistence store.
   at System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting.PersistenceDBAccessor.RetrieveInstanceState(Guid instanceStateId, Guid ownerId, DateTime timeout)
   at System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting.SqlWorkflowPersistenceService.LoadWorkflowInstanceState(Guid id)
   at System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkflowRuntime.InitializeExecutor(Guid instanceId, CreationContext context, WorkflowExecutor executor, WorkflowInstance workflowInstance)
   at System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkflowRuntime.Load(Guid key, CreationContext context, WorkflowInstance workflowInstance)
   at System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkflowRuntime.GetWorkflow(Guid instanceId)
   at System.Workflow.Activities.WorkflowWebService.Invoke(Type interfaceType, String methodName, Boolean isActivation, Object[] parameters)
   at PersistanceWebServiceWorkflow.Workflow1_WebService.PassA(Int32 a) in C:\Users\djpiter\AppData\Local\Temp\2dnwfnsn.cs:line 39
```

Do you have any ideas what I do wrong?

ps:( The database is properly set. I tested it on workflow hosted in console app and delay activity .I also added necessary line to web.config file. )

Kind Regards
PK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one of your activities would throw an exception, the workflow state information would be deleted from the database. Run your workflow debugger with "break when exception is throw" configured in Debug - Exceptions - Common Language Runtime Exceptions

Comment: My activities should not throw any exceptions. I think that I am missing something - after first activity workflow continues to the second activity ... Where is the "break when exception is throw" option?

Comment: See Debug -> Exceptions, check the box after "Common Language Runtime Exceptions"

During what step in the flow do you get the error? Right away when you call PassA to signal webServiceInputActivity1?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why the next day the same code worked ok. Anyways - thanks for your time.